# MySQL Stored Procedure syntax errors using insert into values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

1 `DELIMITER //`
2 `CREATE PROCEDURE createUser(IN emailInput VARCHAR(255), IN passwordHash CHAR(60))`
3 `BEGIN`
4 `insert into UsersTable values(emailInput, " ", passwordHash) //`
5 `END //`
6 `DELIMITER ;`

I get two syntax errors in MySQL when I'm trying to create this stored procedure. Line 4 has a missing semicolon and line 5 says "extraneous input found - expected end of input"

My guess is that I'm using insert into values incorrectly, but this is how I'd form it in a typical command (I think).

Comment: I set the delimiter to `//` on line 1

Answer (score 0):

Foolish me, the "//" delimiter is only for use at the end of the stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createUser(IN emailInput VARCHAR(255), IN passwordHash VARCHAR(255))
  BEGIN
  insert into UsersTable values(emailInput, " ", passwordHash);
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```